# Excel Help, VBA to run a vlookup on a 2nd spreadshet and return value to a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

This is my first time posting to this forum so I am hoping I am asking correctly.

I have a spreadsheet (SiteLookup), where I want the user to enter an address in cell I8.  Then I want to run a VBA script that takes the value in I8 and runs a vlookup on another spreadsheet in the same workbook called SiteInfo.  The value entered should match a value in Column K (address column), then return the corresponding Office name in Column E (office name column).. and place this value back on "SiteLookup" spreadsheet I5, or if no match is made then return "invalid address"

Does that make sense? Can it be done?

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA, you could just use a `=VLOOKUP()` in `I5`, comparing `I8`to the address column. `VLOOKUP` only looks to the right, so you'd have to change places of the columns *(Office name column needs to be on the right of address column)*, or use `=INDEX(MATCH())` instead. For I8, you could use a drop down list of the address column, if you want to list the options. But what you ask can absolutely be done with VBA as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell I8:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(SiteInfo!$E$1,MATCH($I$8,SiteInfo!$K$1:$K$5000,0)-1,0),"Invalid Address")
```